# mysql divide two columns, insert value to another

Tags: mysql, divide

I have a database whith 4 columns (id,cname,ep,gp) where the id is auto incremental, the values in the cname column are unique because they are user names, and the ep and gp columns are number values that are updated frequently.

I want to be able to divide the ep column by the gp column, and either create another column and show the values in it, or insert the values into a null column, whichever is easier

I have created a sqlfiddle to mess with it but I cannot seem to make it work.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e45da/2

any help would be appriciated. thank you

EDIT:

using

```
SELECT  cname,ep, gp,(ep/gp)as lp
FROM     players
order by lp
```

it gives me the data I need, I just have to make it round the lp value to 2 decimal places if possible

Comment: Show your expected result set